# ¿Cómo personalizar el alto de una fila en una tabla HTML?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código `html` para crear una tabla, lo coloco a modo de ejemplo, quiero que las filas de mi tabla se vean mas anchas (si funciona) y las mismas filas se vean mas altas (no funciona), investigando un poco me encontré lo siguiente:

> El atributo `height` no funciona en todos los navegadores, además, su uso no está muy extendido. Las celdas por lo general tienen el alto que necesitan para que quepa todo el contenido que se le haya insertado, es decir, crecen lo suficiente para que quepa lo que hemos colocado dentro.

Se puede hacer lo que quiero directamente en `HTML` o se debe hacer con `CSS`?

```
  <table>
      <tr style="width:130%; height:150%;">
        <td>Enero</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Febrero</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ese efecto utiliza:

- min-width (para el ancho)
- height (el cuál te da la altura real)
- min-height (la altura mínima)
- max-height (la altura máxima)

```css
.headt td {
  min-width: 235px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #433;
}

table {
  color: #4ef;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="headt">
    <td>Enero</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Febrero</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Nota: No puedes usar porcentajes porque para ponerlo así, su `parent element` debe tener una altura explicita, la cual no tiene.

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 3):

Con **CSS** podrías utilizar [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/height), para indicar el alto.

Ejemplo:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Alto de las celdas */
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Enero</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Febrero</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **Nota**: `min-height` y `max-height` aplicados directamente sobre un `td` no funcionan, ya que según el [`spec`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height) el efecto sobre estos no esta definido:
>
> *In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, **table cells**, table rows, and row groups **is undefined**.*

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta es muy buena